# Proving the invertibility of a real-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x)= (b-x)/(1-bx)$ , where $b$ is a constant such that $0<b<1$. Is $f$ invertible on $(0,1)$?

I solved the above question via two methods.

1. Through composition criteria.
   i.e.  if  $g[f(x)]= x$ and $f[g(x)]=y$ holds, then $f$ is invertible.
2. If a function is one-to-one and onto, it is invertible.

The function comes out to be invertible by the first method.
But is not onto.
Can some one help me figure out the mistake?

Comment: You have to distiguish between $x<\frac{1}{b}$ and  $x>\frac{1}{b}$.

Answer (score 2):

The denominator $1-bx$ vanishes for $x=1/b>1$, so the function is indeed defined on $(0,1)$. Now let's solve
$$
y=\frac{b-x}{1-bx}
$$
with respect to $x$, getting
$$
x=\frac{b-y}{1-by}
$$
Note also that
$$
\frac{b-x}{1-bx}=\frac{1}{b}
$$
has no solution, so $y$ never gets the value $1/b$. Therefore the function is invertible.

How can we determine the domain of the inverse? Since $f$ is invertible and obviously continuous, it is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Hence we can compute the limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=b,
\qquad
\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=-1
$$
Thus the range of $f$ (and the domain of the inverse) is $(-1,b)$.

Comment: The range of f is not equal to the co domain. This implies the function is not onto. And hence not invertible. How is the function invertible then?

Comment: @Drishtinarula Somehow “co” slipped in. :( Fixed, thanks.

Comment: So the function is not invertible in (0,1)? Right?

Comment: @Drishtinarula Yes, it is; why shouldn't it be?

Comment: Say if we fix b=0.5 and we take y=1 then we get x= -1 that does not belong to the domain of the function. So we can say that there exists some value of y i.e. 1 for a assumed value of b i.e. 0.5 for which x is not defined. Hence not onto which implies not invertible.

Comment: @Drishtinarula No, you're wrong. In this setting, invertible means injective.

Comment: Invertible means bijection and not only injection.

Comment: @Drishtinarula Check what your textbook means. Since the exercise doesn't specify a codomain, I'm inclined to think you're interpreting wrongly the requirement for invertibility.

Comment: Co domain is R here.

Comment: Check your textbook for the arcsine. If it defines it, then you'll know that invertibility is taken to be the same as injectivity.

Answer (score 0):

If $b\in (0,1)$ then $f(x)=\frac{b-x}{1-bx}$ is defined  and strictly decreasing in $[-1,1]$. Moreover it is easy to see that $f([-1,1])=[-1,1]$. Hence $f$ is bijective from $[-1,1]$ onto $[-1,1]$. Since $f(f(x))=x$ then the inverse is $f$ itself.

It follows that $f$ restricted to $(0,1)$ is invertible (with respect to its image $f((0,1))=(-1,b)$) and its inverse is $f$ restricted to $(-1,b)$.

Comment: Is it onto? Say if we fix b=0.5 and we take y=1 then we get x= -1 that does not belong to the domain of the function. So we can say that there exists some value of y i.e. 1 for a assumed value of b i.e. 0.5 for which x is not defined. Hence not onto.

Comment: I agree with you that if we take as co-domain $\mathbb{R}$ or $(0,1)$ then $f$ is not onto. I said that it is onto if we take as co-domain $(-1,b)$.

Comment: Then that means  f is not invertible in (0,1) .right?

Comment: @Drishti narula $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ is not invertible, $f:(0,1)\to (-1,b)$ is  invertible.

Comment: Yes, correct. Thank you so much. So according to the question i posted above , given the domain and co domain f is not invertible.